# CMake creates file instead of directory

Tags: windows, cmake

Today I encountered a strange behavior when running CMake configuration on a Windows machine.

On most machines, the CMake configuration for the project runs smoothly, all files and directories were correctly created and configured and the code could be build as expected.
But there was one machine, for which the Generate step of CMake **created** for one directory (not a CMake-specific directory, but one reflecting the structure of the source) **an empty file instead of a directory**. So the build stalled there because it cannot create the rest of the necessary build files.

We can manually resolve this by removing the file and creating the wanted directory. After that the rest of the configuration/build is running again.

Did anyone else encounter this kind of issue already? Or have any idea why this could have happened?

Comment: Please, show (add to the question post) **example project** which you are trying to build, and **output** of configuration process (when you run `cmake`).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the rather incomplete question. And I found the culprit meanwhile:

There was a `configure_file` copying a file into one of the build directories; the one which was missing in the end. The point actually was, that it is a) a Windows system, which offers issues when creating directories from a batch file and b) that the `configure_file` was done *before* the corresponding subdirectory had been added to the cmake-build. So something like this:

```
configure_file(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/foo.in ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/bar/foo.txt)
add_subdirectory(bar)
```

the issue can be resolved by:

- creating the directory upfront (well...)
- doing the `add_subdirectory()` before the `configure_file()`
- using `install()` instead of `configure_file()` (which I used, because it made sense in my case)

Comment: Glad you figured out your issue 